# Infinite TextView Vertical Scrolling?

Tags: android, textview

I'm making an android app for a TV and I need a `TextView` that infinitely scrolls content vertically without the user having to scroll using their remote.

Need the text in the blue box of this image to automatically scroll vertically

[image]

I've looked online for some tutorials but most are Horizontally scrolling single line only.

Is there any easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [VerticalMarqueeTextView](https://github.com/tbdawg/VerticalMarqueeTextView) library for TextView vertical scrolling

Answer (score -1):

It takes a number of steps to get this done.

1. Set max lines to your textview via xml or java.
2. Set movement method to your textview as below

   ```
   mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
   ```
3. Create a Timer and on scroll vertically by

   ```
       new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           mTextView.scrollBy(0,1);
       }
   }, 0, 100);
   ```

Play around with scroll by value(1) and timer value(100) to get the speed and smoothness of scrolling right.